# Clear backstack of application in android on button click

Tags: android, android-intent, android-manifest

I am developing app in which i want clear all my back-stack on click of log out button.
i have searched and tried many solutions given but its not working for me.
please if anyone can help me that would be appreciated.

i have tried following code on click of log out button

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

and also tried following code in manifest file

```
android:launchMode="singleTop"
```

Thank you in advanced

Thanx to all of you for your valuable reply

i have found one solution and tried this again was worked for me fine

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.this, MainActivity.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | 
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK |
                Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
finish();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK
                | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

above is working for me but `Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` is available from API 11

Answer (score 0):

use in manifest   android:noHistory="true"

Comment: thank you for ans but i have already tried this and its not working for me