# Finish all activities inside Preference Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-preferences

I have a PreferenceActivity with a custom DialogFragment for clearing the app data, so I want it when the user clicks Yes, the application to either close completely (finish all activities) or just to tell it to go to the InitialSetup activity, so the app ca be set up again anew. So far I havent been able to do it in any way...
Tried with

```
            Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), MySettings.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

but that still does not close all the activities in the back stack...

How can I do it?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21159944/clear-backstack-of-application-in-android-on-button-click/21159985#21159985

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need is `FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK` and `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flags for your intent:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(intent);
```

Or as mentioned Sartheris use `IntentCompat` for Android APIs below 11:

```
Intent intent = IntentCompat.makeRestartActivityTask(new ComponentName(context, MySettings.class));
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: please edit your answer for using IntentCompat for the first flag, it would help people working with older apis

Answer (score 0):

If you only want the app to close, with the user having to start it again later, you can use

```
    System.exit(0);
```

as you would in ordinary Java.

If you want your app to restart automatically after it's closed, use a PendingIntent as the answer for this question does:

[how to programmatically "restart" android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6609414/howto-programatically-restart-android-app)